# clr hosting : give delegate callback to native

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, interop, clr

I am writing a piece of native C++ code that hosts the DotNet CLR, using the COM interfaces (inspired by sample of http://1code.codeplex.com/)

I would like to give the native part a pointer to a Delegate, and then let the native part call that delegate.

Delegate is : `void MyDelegate(string[] args)`

Let me try to explain :
When initializing, I have a method that give managed part a delegate to native function for callbacks registrations, so my callbacks can be registered like this :

```
public void RegisterCallback(MyDelegate cb)
{
    this.Native_Register(cb);
}
```

The native part, I have :

```
void* _cb = NULL;
void Native_RegisterCallback(void* pCallback)
{
    _cb = pCallback;
}
```

When I try to call that callback I have :

```
void Raise_Callback(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(_cb)
    {
        // Create a string array
        // call the callback
    }
}
```

What is the best/recommanded way to raise managed callback from native ?
I have tried with types variant, safearray... tried stdcall, cdecl... Always had runtime errors...

Comment: Use Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate().  And make sure that the GC can see a reference to the delegate as long as the native code can make the callback.  Store it in a static variable or use GCHandle.Alloc().

Comment: I have found this sample that explains your comment : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0(v=vs.80).aspx
but there is still the parameter issue : how can I give a string array as parameters...

Comment: As written you can't, the marshaller can never figure out how many elements are in the array.  You need an extra argument that indicates the length of the array.  The *argc* argument.  Annotate the array with [MarshalAs], SizeParamIndex property.

Comment: I have given up : Instead of passing delegate pointer, I have a dictionary with int id I use...